# Prevent near-plane culling in vertex shader

Tags: culling, vertex-shader

I am rendering a non-sphere light mesh and the standard question is how to cull: cull front faces and you loose Z-Testing benefits, cull back and you get into situations where camera is not rendering parts of the mesh due to near-plane clipping.

I thought myself smart, set culling to back and wrote this code in the vertex shader:

```
o.position = mul(ViewProj, i.worldPos);
if (o.position.z < 0 && o.position.w > 0)
   o.position.z *= -1;
```

This did nothing :). I wanted to ask if I am even thinking in the right direction (whether it is even possible to prevent camera's near-plane culling in the vertex shader)?

Comment: There's a reason to why that happens. Stuff will get rendered incorrectly if it's behind the near plane. The only way to solve this is to not let the camera go inside objects

Comment: Why can't I just tweak projection-space position values to ensure every vertex I render is in front of the camera?

Comment: Because that wouldn't allow you to go in front of objects and it would mess with the perspective projection